# Unable to get the set values from a getter/setter class

Tags: java, javafx

My getter/setter class is the following:

```
package cage;

public class hashtaggs {
private String a;
public String getHashtag()
{
    return a;
}
public void setHashTag(String hashtag)
{
    this.a=hashtag;
    System.out.println(a);
}
}
```

The get method is used in this class

```
public class SaMain extends Application 
{
    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException 
    {
        launch(args);
        hashtaggs h=new hashtaggs();
        String xh=h.getHashtag();
        System.out.println(xh);
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Just a program");
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));
        Text scenetitle = new Text("Choose Your Input Method");
        scenetitle.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 15));
        grid.add(scenetitle,1,0,3,1);
        Button tbtn = new Button();
        tbtn.setText(" Click here for input 1");
        tbtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Input1.fxml"));
                    Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
                    Stage stage = new Stage();
                    stage.setScene(new Scene(root1, 640, 480));  
                    stage.show();
                    ((Node)(event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
                } 
                catch(Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }           
            }
        });
        Button sbtn = new Button();
        sbtn.setText(" Click here to input 2");
        sbtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Input2.fxml"));
                    Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
                    Stage stage = new Stage();
                    stage.setScene(new Scene(root1,640,480));  
                    stage.show();
                } 
                catch(Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }           
            }
        });
        StackPane troot = new StackPane();
        troot.getChildren().add(tbtn);
        StackPane sroot = new StackPane();
        sroot.getChildren().add(sbtn);
        grid.add(troot, 1, 4,3,1);
        grid.add(sroot, 1, 5,3,1);
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 640, 480);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

The `System.out.println(a)` prints the string but I am unable to get the value of the string which is returned as null when I use `getHashtag()`. I'm getting the string value from a controller of a javafx ui entry. I've used `launch(args);` before the get method is used. What could be the problem?

Comment: By this code not easy to understand the problem. You need to explain more and post your complete code.

Comment: Are you sure, you call `getHastTag` after call `setHashTag`?

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: Apparently you are addressing a wrong instance of class `hashtag` when calling `getHashtag()`. In that instance value `a` is not initialized.

Comment: share your code where you use these getter and setter

Comment: I've only added the code of where I've used the getter method because the setter method works fine with the `System.out.println(a)` shows the string name as typed in the javafx UI within the setter method meaning the string value is sent to the getter/setter method

Answer (score 2):

you are not setting the value. you are directly using **getter**.

```
    hashtaggs h=new hashtaggs();
    h.setHashtag(parameter);
    String xh=h.getHashtag();
```

Always remember you need to set value first using **setter**, then only you can access it using **getter**.

For more read this : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm

Comment: The setHashTag is called within the javafx UI which is executed after the launch(args);. Is it that the UI and the back code both work at the same time that is causing the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

In `setHashTag` method you are passing the `string variable` and set it in `a`. And print this value within this method.

If you want get a value by `getHashtag()` then you have to first initialize object means first you have to called `setHashTag` method and the called `getHashtag()`.

This code will work:

```
hashtaggs h=new hashtaggs();
h.setHashTag("string value");
String xh = h.getHashtag();
System.out.println(xh);
```

> Note : As a naming convention class name should start with uppercase
>   letter and be a noun e.g. String, Color

Hopefully this help you.

Comment: The setHashTag is called within the javafx UI which is executed after the `launch(args);`. Is it that the UI and the back code both work at the same time that is causing the issue here?

Comment: Nowhere in the code you posted is `setHashTag` called at all. It is certainly not called on the object you create after the `launch(...)` method completes.